# Ordering sub-collections in an EF/LINQ query

Tags: entity-framework-4, linq-to-entities

I am having trouble figuring out how (and where) to order a subcollection in a LINQ/EF query.

Basically I have a collection of SubscriptionTypes, each having its own collection of Subscriptions. I would like each Subscription in the collection to be ordered by NumberOfMonths.

Here is my current query:

```
    public IQueryable<SubscriptionType> SubscriptionTypesByProperty(string propertyCode)
{
    return from a in db.SubscriptionTypes.Include("Subscriptions")
           where a.Subscriptions.Any(x => x.PropertyCode == propertyCode)
           select a;
}
```

I would like the Subscriptions to be ordered by NumberOfMonths. I tried this:

```
    public IQueryable<SubscriptionType> SubscriptionTypesByProperty(string propertyCode)
    {
        return from a in db.SubscriptionTypes.Include("Subscriptions")
               where a.Subscriptions.OrderBy(q => q.NumberOfMonths).Any(x => x.PropertyCode == propertyCode)
               select a;
    }
```

.. but that did not order the subscriptions correctly.

Does anybody know of an easy way to do this?

UPDATE: SubscriptionType and Subscription are types generated by the EF designer.

Thanks,
Adam

Comment: i don't know how that second query even works - `.Any` returns a `bool`. it should be inside the where as part of the predicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your select part to sth like this

```
   select new SubscriptionType{ ?,?,?, 
                    Subscriptions = a.Subscription.OrderBy(b=>b.?)}
```

Comment: Ah yes I didn't even think about using a projection! I'll give that a try and let you know. Thanks

Comment: I am getting a casting error: Cannot convert source type 'System.Linq.IOrderedEnumerable<Subscription> to type System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.EntityCollection<Subscription>

Comment: No luck - apparently the Subscriptions property of SubscriptionType is of type EntityCollection, so I have to figure out how to convert to that. You have answered my original question so I will mark it as the answer, then open up another question if necessary. Thanks!!

Comment: Good Luck pal, you may look for initializing an EntityCollection by a sequence.

Answer (score 1):

You can change your existing query to this, and it should do what you're looking for.

```
public IQueryable<SubscriptionType> SubscriptionTypesByProperty(string propertyCode)
{
    return from a in db.SubscriptionTypes.Include("Subscriptions")
           where a.Subscriptions.Any(x => x.PropertyCode == propertyCode)
           order by a.NumberOfMonths descending
           select a;
}
```

Obviously, descending could be ascending if that's what you want.

Comment: 'a' in this case is SubscriptionType, while NumberOfMonths is a property of Subscription